# Uns/Umas vs Alguns/Algumas

Tags: significado

When pluralized, the words **um/a** and **algum/a** both translate into English as "some". Therefore, what is the difference between the following sentences?

> Vou comer **umas** maçãs.
>
> Vou comer **algumas** maçãs.

Which is the more common, and which is more correct?

Comment: o mais comum mesmo, seria: *vou comer maças*. Mas das opções, utilizo mais: *vou comer algumas maças*.

Comment: No difference where I come from.  e.g. "por que você não come umas bananas?" and "por que você não come algumas bananas?"  There's no difference to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not much of a difference between the two determinatives.

In the singular, the main difference that exists between *um* and *algum* is the fact that *algum* doesn't admit a [+specific] reading (i.e., a reading where the speaker has a specific entity in mind):

> Vou comer **uma** maçã: a Fuji.
>   *Vou comer **alguma** maçã: a Fuji.

(Another difference is that *algum*, but not *um*, can be put after the noun in certain contexts, like *não vou comer maçã alguma/*uma*.)

In the plural this difference all but disappears:

> Vou comer **umas** maçãs: as três Fujis.
>   Vou comer **algumas** maçãs: as três Fujis.

*Algumas* works more like a quantifier: the difference is small, but with *algumas* you're more clearly referring to small amount of apples. Therefore, with only two items, *algumas* is more awkward (as in *vou comer **algumas** maçãs: esta e aquela*). And if you explicitly request a count, *alguns* is clearly the better option, perhaps the only possible one:

> — Quantas maçãs comeste?
>   — Comi **algumas**. / — ?/* Comi **umas**.

An alternative is to respond with *comi **umas poucas*** (literally *a few*).

Comment: *comi umas poucas* or *comi umas tantas*. There's also *vou comer alguma melancia* ("some watermelon"), whereas *comer uma melancia* would be glutony.

Answer (score 4):

In pt-BR, in a sentence like "*I'll eat some apples*", I'd say that `umas` is more common (`algumas` I'd probably translate in this case as `a few`). Also used is simply

> Vou comer maçã.

But there's very little difference between them in this context. And which one of them sounds best is subjective and, in general, depends strongly on the sentence.

For instance,

> Algumas obras de arte se perderam na guerra.

sounds better than

> Umas obras de arte se perderam na guerra.

Notice also that "*some of them*" is almost always "*alguns deles*" or "*algumas delas*".

Comment: _uns deles_ / _umas delas_ são possíveis, embora menos frequentes: _Foi divulgado na semana passada que um vereador do PMDB gaúcho não apenas propôs publicamente o assassinato de crianças ele próprio disse que tentou matar umas delas, passando o carro por cima_

Comment: @Artefacto Verdade. Corrigido.

Comment: bem visto que _a few_ é uma melhor tradução para _algumas_

Comment: I'd say in Portugal too, *comer umas maçãs* is more common than *algumas maçãs*